# AWS CLI cloudformation validate-template success but getting error during create-stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Good day.
I made changes in the Condition section wherein

1. I have Con1 as the 1st condition
2. Then Con2 as the 2nd that is using the Con1

In `aws cloudformation validate-template` the result is success.
But when I start using the create-stack via `aws cloudformation create-stack`, then I get the error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Template error: Fn::If cannot be preprocessed
```

This is the changes I made in the Condition section.

```js
  "Conditions": {
    "Con1": {
      "Fn::Not": [{
        "Fn::Equals": [
          {"Ref": "Environment"},
          "abc"
        ]
      }]
    },
    "Con2": {
      "Fn::Not": [{
        "Fn::Equals": [
          { "Fn::If": 
            [
              "Con1", 
              { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "iamRoles", {"Ref": "HostnameAppId"},  "abc"] },
              { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "iamRoles", {"Ref": "HostnameAppId"},  "xyz"] }
            ]
          },
          ""]
        }]
      }
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, `Fn::If` is **not supported** in `Conditions`. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if):

> Currently, AWS CloudFormation **supports** the Fn::If intrinsic function in the metadata attribute, update policy attribute, and property values in the Resources section and Outputs sections of a template.

Comment: Oh ok, so only Fn::If can only be used in Resources and Output sections. Thanks for the link, I should have seen that. I was mislead by the validate-template being successful.

Comment: @CarlosJaimeC.DeLeon No problem. Its easy to miss.

Answer (score 2):

While [`aws cloudformation validate-template`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/validate-template.html) doesn't validate much, the [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/) will catch these issues before deploying:

`E8003 Fn::Equals element must be a supported function (Ref, Fn::FindInMap, Fn::Sub, Fn::Join, Fn::Select, Fn::Split)`

[image: Visual Studio Code extension screenshot]

The [Visual Studio Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kddejong.vscode-cfn-lint) can show these errors inline while authoring templates

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering how to detect this error without executing a create-stack.